# manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 ImportError No module named DBCONN

Tags: python, django

I am running the manage.py runserver and getting an import error for "dbconn"  The file exists in the django project directory.  Here is the directory listing of my django project.  Also below this I have included my traceback.  If anyone has any ideas, I am learning django on the fly.

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cchadwick cchadwick 1230 Jun  1 12:30 chartcall.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cchadwick cchadwick 1651 Jun  1 12:24 dbconn.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cchadwick cchadwick    0 May 26 14:43 __init__.py
drwxrwxr-x. 2 cchadwick cchadwick  240 Jun  1 12:30 __pycache__
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cchadwick cchadwick 3569 Jun  1 11:58 settings.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cchadwick cchadwick  959 May 30 14:10 urls.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cchadwick cchadwick  181 May 31 15:04 views.py
-rw-rw-r--. 1 cchadwick cchadwick  396 May 26 14:43 wsgi.py


(dbenv) [cchadwick@opendev-cutco-com dashproj1]$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f4d001ce488>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils   /autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django /core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 94, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "/home/cchadwick/dbenv/lib64/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'dbconn'
```

Here is the code for the dbconn file.

```
import pyodbc

def db2conn():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
    driver='{iSeries Access ODBC Driver}',
    system="0.0.0.0",
    uid='USER',
    pwd='PASS')

    c1 = conn.cursor()
    return c1, conn
```

This is the chartcall.py

```
#import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure 
from bokeh.io import output_file, save, show
from time import sleep
from pandas import DataFrame, read_sql_query, to_numeric, options,    set_eng_float_format, formats
from geopy import Nominatim, geocoders
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
import gmplot
import geocoder
from bokeh.models import (Range1d, PanTool, ResetTool, HoverTool,   ColumnDataSource, LabelSet,
                      GMapPlot, GMapOptions, DataRange1d, PanTool, WheelZoomTool, BoxSelectTool, Circle)
#from django.db import Connection
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from tkinter import *
#import dbconn 



c1, conn = db2conn()


def orders_by_day():
    sql = """ Select count(doord#) total_ords, sum(dolin1) total_lin1   from dmfiles.dmordm0 
              join dmfiles.bncchan0 on dootyp = ordertype 
              and doomtd = ordermethod 
              where 
              doocat = 'ORD' and doco# = '00004' and channel = 'Catalog'
              and doshpd between current_date - 1 days and current_date

             """

     x = []

     y = []
     i = 0
     c1.execute(sql)
     for row in c1.execute(sql):
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[1])

     return x, y
```

Comment: How are you trying to import `dbconn`? And _why_ are you doing this? What's wrong with Django's built-in database handling via `settings.py`?

Comment: all this dbconn is basically a db properties type of file with a bunch of connections.  I am importing it through git from my local pc to linux..  Which the file exists in the django project but when I runserver I get the import failed.  I havent used the django build in db handling i have no idea how that works.  I am pretty new to django.

Comment: "I am importing it through git from my local pc to linux"—I have no idea what you're trying to say here. But the question is how you're trying to import it _in your Python code_. It might be helpful to see the contents of the file as well (be sure to remove any sensitive information!) You should probably take the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/); it introduces most of the core Django concepts, including data modeling and database connections.

Comment: I have added the dbconn code for you to see.  I will go through that tutorial you suggested.

Comment: _You still haven't shown how you're trying to **import** `dbconn`_. I also just noticed that you've got a `views.py` file beside your `settings.py` and `wsgi.py` files… normally you `views.py` files live inside Django _apps_, not inside the Django project directory. Where did `view.py` come from? I'm glad that you've decided to go through the tutorial. It's quite good, and should help you sort through some of this stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I am importing dbconn into another homemade python file called chartcall.py.  I will include the code to that as well.  I didnt create any apps for this project because alot of the processes are stand alone.   views.py was created by me after running the manage.py startproject.